# Unable to Search the database using Where clause with string field

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code

```
public static function getRecord($query){ // Gets single record and returns single associative array
        db::open();
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
            $recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            }else{
                $recordset = false;
            }
        db::close();
        return ($recordset);
    }

$query = "SELECT * FROM callDetails WHERE storeName = " . $name ;
```

I am getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'E Jewelers LIMIT 0, 50' at line 1
```

The $name is 'A E Jewelers'

Comment: Use PHP's MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements/bind variables rather than the old, deprecated MySQL extension; and with bind variables you'll never need worry about forgetting to quote string values in your SQL statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM callDetails WHERE storeName = '" . $name ."'";
```

Comment: Don't guide people to use variable inside queries

Comment: PDO is best alternative